# Issues with Implementing Retention Policy in Loki

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

Need help with implementing retention policy in loki.

```yaml
  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: xxxxx-loki-chunks
      ruler: xxxxx-loki-ruler
      admin: xxxxx-loki-admin
    type: s3
    s3:
      region: af-south-1
      s3ForcePathStyle: false
      insecure: false

  compactor:
    apply_retention_interval: 1h
    working_directory: /data/loki/compactor
    shared_store: s3
    compaction_interval: 1h
    retention_enabled: true
    retention_delete_delay: 2h
    retention_delete_worker_count: 150
    #retention_deletes_enabled: true
    #retention_period: 72h # 3 days

  schema_config:
    configs:
      - from: 2020-10-24
        store: boltdb-shipper
        object_store: s3
        schema: v11
        index:
          prefix: index_
          period: 24h
```

I got error while deploying the loki.

```
level=error ts=2024-02-28T06:55:55.837069723Z caller=log.go:230 msg="error running loki" err="mkdir /data: read-only file systemerror initialising module: 
compactor github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).initModule  
    /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:138  
github.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices  
    /src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:108  
github.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run  
    /src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:461  
main.main  
    /src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:110  
runtime.main  
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267  
runtime.goexit  
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650"
```